# apache SSLCertificate does not exist

Tags: windows, apache, ssl-certificate

I am installing Apache HTTP server `httpd-2.2.31-x86` for Windows 7.

I get error about some SSL Certificate file when I try to execute `httpd.exe` saying:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache22\bin>httpd.exe
Syntax error on line 110 of C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache22/conf/extra/httpd-ahs
sl.conf:

SSLCertificateFile: file 'C:/Apache22/conf/ssl/server.crt' does not exist or is
empty".
```

When I open that folder the file server (as Security Certificate) exists.

I tried to open that file and it installed something and said Installation complete. But then again the error pops.

Comment: `Syntax error on line 110 of ` what is this line in your config file? You probably did something wrong. Show this line.

Comment: Also are you sure that path is correct? You are showing 2 different paths. `C:/Apache22/` and `C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache22/` You might have forgotten to put the full path in the config to the SSL cert.

Comment: I should have extracted it to "C:/" instead of  "C:/Program Files (x86)/".

Thanks @PanamaJack

Comment: Also see http://serverfault.com/q/416612/87017